# React Native ImageView won't stretch out

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to implement a custom ObjC SpriteSheet in React Native. I'm able to get everything exported fine, but the issue is, when I try to display it, it gets set to 0 width and height. I've tried declaring it as they say in the tutorial, with `style={{ flex: 1 }}`, but that does nothing. If I set style as so: `style={{ flex: 1, width: 224, height: 225 }}`, I can see my ImageView perfectly, it's not animating, but that's an issue for another day.

Is there anything special that needs to be done to get a `UIImageView` to expand in React Native? All my view is is a `UIImageView` with each individual sprite set as it's animatable images.

I've tried setting constraints on the actual view itself, but that doesn't work. I've checked the `intrinsicContentSize` property, but that doesn't work. I'm trying to look for a way to pass the height and width needed to React Native, but am running into issues with that.

Does anyone know how to either properly display a `UIImageView` in React Native and get it to stretch out to the image size, or how to pass information into the React Native side about the ObjC view I'm trying to display?

Answer (score 0):

Do you load the Images dynamically from the Web ? If so you might run into trouble if you don't declare set Dimensions (width and height) for the Image. If you want it to be fullscreen you could get the window width via

```
Dimensions.get("window").width
```

Comment: We don't load from the web, it's coming from within the app, but I'm finding that unless I manually set the dimensions, React is setting it to 0 width and height. I don't want it to be the full screen size, but instead the same size as the image contained within it.

Comment: Have you tried using React Native's [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) Component ? This would certainly solve your issue if your files are coming from within the App.

Comment: We have tried it, the issue with that is there's a persistent "flashing" effect that we don't have in our native view, which is why we're trying to bring it over from iOS native.

Comment: @BillL have you also deployed and tested on a real device ? Sometimes components have weird behaviour when run on an emulator or within expo...